# Find a code to execute gmailr in DOCKERFILE

Tags: gmailr

I just want a send gmail message using gmailr R package and PUT in DOCKER SCRIPT. But i have problem with authentication!

```
Error in `gm_auth()`:
! Can't get Google credentials.
✖ No OAuth client has been configured.
```

My code:

```
gm_auth(token = gm_token_read(path = "secrets/gmailr-token.rds"))
gm_auth_configure(path = 'secrets/gmailkey.json"', cache = TRUE)
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Create a token!  When i execute in docker bash, but in 'docker comand, docker run' not working

Comment: I tried only this code
`gm_auth_configure(path = 'secrets/gmailkey.json')`
`gm_auth(email = 'myemail@gmail.com', cache = TRUE)`

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Does that file exist? Does it contain what it should contain?